# Why is my destructor called twice?

Tags: c++, destructor

Suppose I hace a class Student with the method:

```
Student Student::method(Student x)
{
    //nothing important
    return x;
}
```

The copy constructor is called twice, once when the object x is send as a parameter and second when x is returned from the function.

Why **and when** is the destructor for class Student called twice when I call this method?
The call is like this: a = b.method(c), where a, b and c are Student objects.

Comment: Is the question about the constructor or the destructor? The title says one thing, the question body the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, `a = b.method(c);`, there are three copies that may take place, save for copy elision. The first is when the `c` object is copied into the function parameter `x`. The second is when the `x` object is returned from the function. The third is when the return value is copied into the `a` object. The first two involve the copy constructor and the last involves the copy assignment operator, unless you change it to `Student a = b.method(c);`, in which case they all use the copy constructor.

`a`, `b`, and `c` will all be destroyed at the end of their scope. The object `x` will be destroyed at the end of the `method` function. The return value of the function will be destroyed at the end of the full expression that contains it - that is, once `a = b.method(c);` has finished.

However, not all of these copies must occur - the compiler is allowed to *elide* or omit the copy/move construction of a class under certain situations. The first copy into the function parameter will occur. The second copy out of the function will be treated as a move first, before attempting to copy it. This copy or move may be elided. The final copy, from temporary return value to `a`, will occur if you're using copy assignment, but may be elided if you use the copy constructor (as in `Student a = b.method(c);`).

Answer (score 1):

If two Student objects are constructed, they must be destructed. The copies into the parameter and out of the return value need destructing.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor for `x` is called when the function returns (after `x` has been copied in to the return value).

The destructor for the return value is called at the end of the full-expression containing the function call (unless the return value has its lifetime extended by being assigned to a reference).

Every object with automatic storage duration that is constructed will automatically be destructed (usually in reverse order of construction). You construct two objects (`x` and the return value) and so there are two destructor calls.

Comment: So after the line where i assign the object returned by b.method(c) to a that object is destroyed? This has nothing to do with the =, right?

Comment: @Sorin: Correct. The only part where it becomes tricky that "copy elision" is allowed in some situations, so for example `Student a(b.method(c));` may (or may not, it is not specified) construct the return value directly in the `a` object, thus extending the lifetime of the return value. Also `Student const& a(b.method(c));` will (definitely) extend the lifetime of the return value to the scope of the `a` reference.